# How to get GetBindingExpression target reflective

Tags: c#, silverlight, dependency-properties

i could need some help on something i can't figure out at this point:

I need to update XAML-Bindings (via a class to varying resx-files) on a certain event for controls with a specific name prefix. As the controls have different types and i do no know how the same page will look somewhen in the future, i'd like to do that with reflections only...

something like

```
var meth1 = control.GetType().GetMethod("GetBindingExpression");
var meth2 = control.GetType().GetMethod("SetBinding");
BindingExpression be = (BindingExpression)meth1.Invoke(target, null);
Binding bind = be.ParentBinding;
meth2.Invoke(target, new object[] { bind });
```

seems to be the right idea to me, but i cannot figure out how to get the target DependencyProperty from a DependencyObject without knowing the DependencyObject Type before...

I am pretty sure i am missing something rather easy here ...

[edit]
I know that i can go through the controls and just enter the new string i get from a ResourceManager Object into the e.g. Text-Property of the Control, but in that case i'd again have to check for Text, Header, whatever properties ... if possible, reflections only seem the cleaner way to me.

Comment: Why can't you cast your control to FrameworkElement and use methods directly instead of reflection?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use following way,

```
FrameworkElement fe = control as FrameworkElement;
foreach(PropertyDescriptor pd in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(control))
{
   FieldInfo field = control.GetType().GetField(pd.Name + "Property");
   if(field == null)
       continue;
   DependencyProperty dp = field.GetValue(control) as DependencyProperty;
   if(dp == null)
       continue;
   BindingExpression be = control.GetBindingExpression(dp);
   if(be == null)
       continue;

   // do your stuff here

}
```

Comment: thanks, this took me back in the right direction. The above does not work as silverlight does not know the TypeDescriptor class, but i got it done as below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the both hints regarding the cast to FrameworkElement, i managed to get back on track:

```
foreach (var f in control.GetType().GetFields())
    {
        DependencyProperty dp = f.GetValue(control) as DependencyProperty;
        if (dp != null)
        {
            BindingExpression be = ((FrameworkElement)control).GetBindingExpression(dp);
            if (be != null)
            {
                // stuff here
            }
        }
     }
```

From here on i think will get things done